# Reindexing multi-index dataframes in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to reindex one multi-index dataframe based on another multi-index dataframe. For singly-indexed dfs, this works:

```
index1 = range(3, 7)
index2 = range(1, 11)
values = [np.random.random() for x in index1]

df = pd.DataFrame(values, index=index1, columns=["values"])

print(df)
print(df.reindex(index2, fill_value=0))
```

Output:

```
     values
3  0.458003
4  0.945828
5  0.783369
6  0.784599
      values
1   0.000000
2   0.000000
3   0.458003
4   0.945828
5   0.783369
6   0.784599
7   0.000000
8   0.000000
9   0.000000
10  0.000000
```

New rows are added, based on `index2`, and the value for `y` is set to `0`. This is what I expect.

Now, let's try something similar for a multi-index df:

```
data_dict = {
    "scan": 1,
    "x": [2,3,5,7,8,9],
    "y": [np.random.random() for x in range(1,7)]
}

index1 = ["scan", "x"]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict).set_index(index)
print(df)

index2 = list(range(4, 13))
print(df.reindex(index2, level="x").fillna(0))
```

Output:

```
               y
scan x          
1    2  0.771531
     3  0.451761
     5  0.434075
     7  0.135785
     8  0.309137
     9  0.838330
               y
scan x          
1    5  0.434075
     7  0.135785
     8  0.309137
     9  0.838330
```

What gives? The output is different than the input: the first two values have been removed. But the other values - intermediate (e.g., `4`) or larger (e.g., `10` or higher) - are not there. What am I missing?

The actual dataframes have 6 index levels and tens to hundreds of rows, but I think this code captures the problem. I spent a little time looking at `df.realign`, `df.join`, and a lot of time scouring SO, but I haven't found a solution. Apologies if it's a duplicate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me suggest a workaround:

```
print(df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.get_level_values(0).unique(), index2], names=['scan', 'x'])).fillna(0))
                y
scan x           
1    4   0.000000
     5   0.718190
     6   0.000000
     7   0.612991
     8   0.609323
     9   0.991806
     10  0.000000
     11  0.000000
     12  0.000000
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for this example. But I'm not clear on how you reindex across multiple levels (in my case, 6 levels). Do you list each level in the list arg to `.from_product([])`?

Comment: Trying it with two levels works; trying it with the six levels I have crashes the kernel. Hrm.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Sergey's workaround, here's what I ended up with. I expanded the example to have more levels, more closely replicating my own data.

Generate a df:

```
data_dict = {
    "sample": "A", 
    "scan": 1,
    "meas_time": datetime.now(),
    "x": [2,3,5,7,8,9],
    "y": [np.random.random() for x in range(1,7)]
}

index1 = ["sample", "scan", "meas_time", "x"]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict).set_index(index1)
print(df)
```

Try to reindex:

```
index2 = range(4, 13)
print(df.reindex(labels=index2, level="x").fillna(0))
```

Implementing Sergey's workaround:

```
df.reindex(
    pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        [df.index.get_level_values("sample").unique(),
         df.index.get_level_values("scan").unique(),
         df.index.get_level_values("meas_time").unique(),
         index2], 
        names=["sample", "scan", "meas_time", "x"])
    ).fillna(0)
```

Notes: if `.unique()` isn't included, a multiple (product?!?) of the dataframe is calculated for each level. This is likely why my kernel crashed previously; I wasn't including `.unique()`.

This seems like really odd `pandas` behavior. I also found a workaround which involved chaining `.reset_index().set_index("x").reindex("blah").set_index([list])`. I'd really like to know why reindexing is treated the way it is.